# Python cryptography fails with "Expected interface of CipherAlgorithm"

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to use the cryptography python module ([cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io)) but cannot implement a working example. [From example in documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/).

This code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import openssl
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

dbackend = default_backend
iv = 'ababababcdcdcdcd1212121234343434'.encode('hex')
cipher = Cipher(modes.CBC(iv), algorithms.AES('aabbccddaabbccdd1122334411223344'.decode('hex')), backend=dbackend)

e = cipher.encryptor()
ct = e.update("Secret messagexx") + e.finalize()

d = cipher.decryptor()

clear = d.update(ct) + d.finalize()
```

fails with:

```
cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: Backend object does not implement CipherBackend.
```

I then try with openssl backend:

```
obackend = openssl.backend
cipher = Cipher(modes.CBC(iv), algorithms.AES('aabbccddaabbccdd1122334411223344'.decode('hex')), backend=obackend)
```

And it fails with:

```
TypeError: Expected interface of CipherAlgorithm.
```

I've been trying to read the docs but I can't even get the example code to work. Any help appreciated.

**Update - solved**:

In case someone stumbles over this I add this working example here (where I use ECB mode which was what I actually wanted).

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

backend = default_backend()
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES('aabbccddaabbccdd1122334411223344'.decode('hex')), modes.ECB(), backend=backend)

e = cipher.encryptor()
ct = e.update("Secret messagexx") + e.finalize()

d = cipher.decryptor()

clear = d.update(ct) + d.finalize()

print clear
```

Comment: From the documentation you linked to "This is a “Hazardous Materials” module. You should ONLY use it if you’re 100% absolutely sure that you know what you’re doing because this module is full of land mines, dragons, and dinosaurs with laser guns."

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I thought that someone here has been using it know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `default_backend` as the backend argument, but that's actually a function. Call it with `default_backend()` and it will return a backend object you can pass in.

The non-hazmat layer does contain a symmetric encryption recipe (known as [Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/)), so you may want to consider using that if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that was one error. Another error was that I had, due to some error message I got earlier, changed the order of modes and algorithms.